# Add a tuple-based check to this relation

Tags: sql, database, check-constraints

> In relation Person (SSN, State, Name), add a tuple-based check: if a
>   person’s State is NY, then the first three digits of his SSN has to be
>   between ‘050’ and ‘134’. (Hint: use LEFT function in SQL).

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    SSN   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    State   CHAR(50),
    Name  CHAR(100),
    CHECK ( 
        SELECT LEFT (SSN, 3) AS FirstThreeDigits, SSN FROM Person,
        WHERE Person.State == ‘NY’) between '050' and between '134'
);
```

I am not comfortable with the CHECK condition here. I am not sure if this is the right way doing conditional check. Can someone please verify this? If not, how do we do a conditional check?

We need this:

```
if state == 'NY', perform CHECK
```

Do we need a trigger? I was thinking that if a new insert / update occurs, check the value. But the question doesn't ask that.

Comment: @Conrad Frix It's just SQL statement. Non-platform specific. It's an introductory course. Thanks. So I think any general SQL statements will be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so its generic but DDL typically isn't but lets use the doc on [SQL Server CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) as a guide anyway

> You can create a CHECK constraint with any logical (Boolean)
>   expression that returns TRUE or FALSE based on the logical operators.
>   For the previous example, the logical expression is:
>   `salary >= 15000 AND salary <= 100000.`

Note that the above example from the docs is *not* a SELECT statement but and expression. This means all you need to do is come up with a expression that returns TRUE

when all of the following are true

1. State is NY
2. The Left three digits of the SSN  is => ‘050’
3. The Left three digits of the SSN  is <=  134.

Or

1. Sate is not NY

Remembering that you can Group a set of logical expressions in a Parens

e.g.

```
(Group of logical expressions) OR (Group of logical expressions)
```

It shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am struggle with the fact that the check is performed ONLY when state is == NY, then we do the check on the digits. How do I do that? If all three are fasle, the check will be false, and reject the modification. That's not what the problem want, I think. I think I can use `between` to check the digits?

Comment: Ahhh. I tend to complicated things. Thanks Conrad! You are right. :( Thanks. You've given a big hint before.